# Style the font for <select> and <option> tags in FireFox / Mozilla

Tags: firefox, fonts, html-select, mozilla

The font between the `<option>` tags cannot be changed with CSS in FireFox. (It can be done, using normal CSS statements, in Chrome.) I can change the font for the `<select>` part of the statement using CSS, so that the selected option appears in my desired font, but the text between the `<option>` tags in the dropdown list are always in FireFox's default font. This is important because I want to use a monospace font in the option tags.

Can I gain control over style of the font in the `<option>` tag in FireFox?

My clients are telling me they used to see the monospace font in a dropdown select list in FireFox - until a few weeks ago. Did FireFox change the way they render a directive to change the font using CSS in the `<option>` and `<select>` tags? Does anyone know?

I have read that "the standard" does not specify that the contents between the option tags must be stylable - but that some browsers, like Chrome, render the CSS anyway, while FireFox does not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

The question has not been answered. It seems impossible to change the font of the

```
<option>content</option>
```

text between the option tags in FireFox. It does work in Chrome.

Comment: Came to this post after wasting my time for a day...Hence Proved :D

Comment: There are bugreports open @ mozilla about this issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1421524 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1536148

Answer (score 1):

The font-family between the  tags cannot be changed with CSS in Firefox so you can best use this plugin converts the select tag into span so we can apply font-family on span.
and it gives you default search bar if you need.

plugin link- https://select2.org/

Answer (score 0):

As of Firefox 52, you are now able to style the content in the option tag:

```
<option>content</option>
```

You can [test it out on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/cobobidoxi/2/edit?html,css,output).

So far, I've tested color, font family, font style, and size.

Both inline styles and stylesheet declarations now work on Firefox.

Comment: It's funny/sad that Firefox can change the colour from option to option but dropped support for selecting the font, even through inheritance form the parent select element.

Comment: @Kevin_Lee_Garner I looked at the JS Bin, and it seems like now unfortunately it only works for the inline style declarations.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a duplicate because it appears after last FireFox update (now v52.0 x32), before the update FF showed text in OPTION with correct styles of font.

UPD: In single process window mode styles of font in OPTION are showing right, in multi process mode are not.
To switch on/off multi process mode type about:config in address line and find option "browser.tabs.remote.autostart"