# What is the status of CSS font support for <option> elements in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, font-face, webfonts

There have been a number of questions about Firefox’ (lack of) support for styling `<select>` and `<input>` elements. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515909) is the most recent one I could find, but the most recent answer there is over a year old and clearly not correct anymore.

In Firefox 65 (which I had installed up until a moment ago), [Vinay Chaudhari’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52437261/1302127) from September 2018 was correct: styling `<option>` does not seem to work at all.

In Firefox 69 (which I just updated to) as well as in Firefox DE 70, however, it does seem to work… sort of:

- **Padding**, **margin**, **display**, **line-height**, **(min-)width/height** don’t seem to work at all (not too surprising), but nor does something like **text-transform** (more surprising)
- **Font-size** and **font-style** appear to work as expected
- **Font-family** seems to work, but only for system fonts
- Others..?

I’m specifically interested in `font-family` here. I’m pulling in a web font (Fira Sans) from Typekit, which is used everywhere on the page I’m working on at the moment, including in the `<option>` elements. This works fine in most browsers, but Firefox uses the fallback system font (in my case `sans-serif`, rendering Helvetica on my machine).

So there seems to be an ongoing effort to get styling to work on `<option>` elements as well – but as the answers to the linked question show, previous versions have had this and then removed it again later on.

I couldn’t find anything about what the actual intent and process from Mozilla are on this, hence this question:

#### What is the current status, as well as the intentions among the developers, of CSS support in Firefox (and Firefox DE) for `<option>` elements, particularly concerning font family, especially web fonts?